# Implementations of Java dynamic proxy

Tags: java, dynamic, proxy

Can you suggest any popular frameworks/tools that use Java dynamic proxy feature in a big way? I can think of Spring AOP and EasyMock. Are there any other good examples?

I need this information for a blog of mine on Java proxies where I feel the content can be more useful if I describe some good implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java RMI has used these @since 1.5.

Comment: Thanks! Based on your RMI clue, I'm able to find few other references as well. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08305/index.html has an introduction paragraph on some of the implementations.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2000/jw-1110-proxy.html#resources

http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html#intro

The above link can help you

Comment: Thanks! Links you provided give useful information on dynamic proxies. But I'm looking for some sample implementations (commerical and/or open source). As mentioned, Spring AOP and EasyMock are the ones I believe use Java proxies. Any other such implementations?